# get Various types of address used

Tags: linux, memory, linux-kernel, virtual-memory

How to get various address ranges of a running machine or a crash dump?

- User virtual address
- Physical address
- Bus address
- Kernel logical address
- Kernel virtual address

I don't need the bus address.

for eg: physical address range 0x00000000 to 0xffffffff

I am testing [crash utility](http://people.redhat.com/~anderson/) so I need these values to verify functions of crash utility.

Ref: [Address types used in Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71174/address-types-used-in-linux)

Comment: crash dump of what exactly? Kernel or a userspace app?

Comment: I don't understand your question. You want the addresses of what exactly?

Comment: @peterph, crash dump of  kernel

Comment: @Mat, address range

Comment: Address range of what? I really don't understand what your asking. Could you please try and describe that in more detail by [edit]ing your question?

Answer (score 1):

The `crash` utility should fit your need, the best tool for crash dump analysis.

[Download source code and read help document here](http://people.redhat.com/~anderson/)

Comment: i am actually testing crash utility.